# C# LASER Circling gesture usage

Tags: c#, .net, computer-vision, gesture

In my program the user can interact with LASER pointer on a Large display, LASER will carryout an action like opening a file by making a circle around it.

My code is detecting drawing a circle, I want to predict when the user start to make this circle during his continuous movement. I want to find the when the user start to make circle and the start point of this circle.

```
 Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
       Rectangle a = (Rectangle)r;
       global.PointX[global.LastIndex] = a.Location.X;
       global.PointY[global.LastIndex] = a.Location.Y;
       global.LastIndex++;
       Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(160, 255, 160), 3);
       Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(b);
       pen1 = new Pen(color, 3);
       SolidBrush b5 = new SolidBrush(color);


       Font f = new Font(Font, FontStyle.Bold);

       g2.DrawString("o", f, b5, a.Location);
       g2.Dispose();
       pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)b;

       if (global.LastIndex > 1)
       {
               if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(global.PointX[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.PointX[0], 2) + Math.Pow(global.PointY[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.PointY[0], 2)) < Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(global.PointX[global.LastIndex - 2] - global.PointX[0], 2) + Math.Pow(global.PointY[global.LastIndex - 2] - global.PointY[0], 2)))
               {
                   global.CloseToBeCircle = true;
               }
               global.angle[global.LastIndex] = System.Math.Atan2(global.PointY[global.LastIndex - 2] - global.PointY[global.LastIndex - 1], global.PointX[global.LastIndex - 2] - global.PointX[global.LastIndex - 1]) * 180 / System.Math.PI;

               if (global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] < 0)
                   global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] += 360;

               if (global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] > 270 && global.angle[global.LastIndex - 2] < 90)
               {
                   global.angle[global.LastIndex - 2] += 360;
               }
               else if (global.angle[global.LastIndex - 2] > 270 && global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] < 90)
               {
                   global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] += 360;
               }

               if (global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.angle[global.LastIndex - 2] > 0)
               {
                   global.IsPositive[global.PositiveIndex++] = true;

               }
               else if (global.angle[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.angle[global.LastIndex - 2] < 0)
                   global.IsNegative[global.NegativeIndex++] = true;

               //if (global.IsPositive[15] == true || global.IsNegative[15] == true)
               if (global.CloseToBeCircle)
               {
                   if ((global.PositiveIndex > global.NegativeIndex && global.NegativeIndex == 0) || (global.NegativeIndex > global.PositiveIndex && global.PositiveIndex == 0))
                   {
                       if (Math.Pow(global.PointX[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.PointX[0], 2) <= 25 || Math.Pow(global.PointY[global.LastIndex - 1] - global.PointY[0], 2) <= 25)
                       {
                           flush();
                           this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show("Circle");
                           });
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Comment: Please ask a question.